# O que são parâmetros rest?

Tags: javascript

Recentemente eu descobri que existem [Parâmetros Rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) no *JavaScript* que possui a seguinte sintaxe:

```
function (a, b, ...c) {
    // Code.
}
```

Mas não entendi muito bem o que são, para que serve e como podem ser útil a sua utilização no código.